# Probability of quadratic equation having real roots

Tags: probability

What is the probability of quadratic equation $x^2 + 2px + q = 0$ having real roots if we choose p and q randomly from the interval $[-1; 1]$ ?

I know that in order for the following equation to have real roots, inequality $p^2 \geq q$ must be valid
and if q is negative (probability $\frac{1}{2}$),  $p^2$ is always more than $p$ but what about the positive half ?

I got that the possibility is $\frac{4 - \sqrt{2})}{4}$ but I'm really not sure.

Comment: Did you mean $x^2+2px+q=0$?

Comment: Yes, sorry, I'm new.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The equation has real roots if and only if the discriminant $d = (2p)^2 - 4q \ge 0$, or equivalently, $q \le p^2$.

Since the point $(p,q)$ is randomly chosen from square region $S$ defined by
\begin{align*}
&-1\le p \le 1\\[4pt]
&-1 \le q \le 1\\[4pt]
\end{align*}
in the $pq$-plane, the required probability is the area of $D$ divided by the area of $S$, where $D$ is the subregion of $S$ between the line $q = -1$ and the parabola $q=p^2$.

It follows that the area of $D$ is the value the integral
$$\int_{-1}^1\;\left(p^2 - (-1)\right)\,dp$$
and of course, the area of $S$ is just the area of a $2{\,\times\,}2$ square.

Answer (score 1):

[image]

Calculate the area of the shaded region. What is this as a ratio of the whole square ?

Answer (score 0):

For remainder integrate $$y=x^2$$ over the span (-1,1). Its equal to 2/3.So you final answer is equal to (2+2/3)/4 or 2/3